# css float not working in some mobile browsers

Tags: css, css-float

As seen in the picture below, this is what I get in some mobile browsers like samsung default browser, UC browser - a white space between header and nav bar. In google chrome mobile, opera, this problem is not to be seen.

The header and nav bar have applied float:left to them. And if I remove the left float to nav bar, there appears a white space in other browsers as well.

This shows that float is not being applied in some mobile browsers mentioned above.

Please give solution for this.

This is my code (jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/jtv7o9yb/)

Html -

```
<div class="head">
   <div class="head-wrapper">
     <div class="logo">
       LOGO
     </div>
     <div class="tagline">
       Tagline
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="main-nav" >
  <ul class="nav_bar">
     <li class="nav_bar-1">
     </li>
     <li class="nav_bar-2">
     </li>
     <li class="nav_bar-2">
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Css -

```
.head {
    background-color:#000000;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: unset;
    float: left;
    color: white;
}

.head-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
.logo{
    width: 18%;
    float: left;
    padding: 11px 0px 11px 0px;
}
.tagline {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.main-nav {
        background-color: red;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
}
li.nav_bar-1 {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 14%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 4%;
}
li.nav_bar-2 {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 11%;
    padding-left: 9%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 766px){
.main-nav {
        width: 100% !Important;
        padding-left: 0px;
        float: left;
    }

}
```

[image: Gap between Header and Nav bar in some mobile browsers]

Comment: can you link css?

Comment: Code and css both, please create a snippet

Comment: Please give us a repdorucable problem before asking for a solution!

Comment: @AndersSørensen  Added Html and Css code to the question. Please see.

Comment: @AnmolSandal Added Html and Css code to the question. Please see.